# Idiomatic way for single-expressions procs in nim

Tags: nim-lang

Why do I see

```
proc simple(a, b: int) : int =
  result = a + b
```

so often in nim code when it seems as if

```
proc simple(a, b: int) : int =
  a + b
```

would suffice? Is there any semantic difference between those two that I'm missing?

The only reference to implicitly returning the last statement I found on nim-lang wasn't in the [manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-return-statement) but in the [tut](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html) where it states that

> [...] a proc's body can consist of a single expression whose value is
>   then returned implicitly.

Which seems misleading: it seems as it works for every 'last expression' (unless result was already set, then the result of the statement has to be discarded)

Answer (score 3):

In the coding conventions (https://nim-lang.org/docs/nep1.html#introduction-coding-conventions) they recommend to use `return` only if it's needed in the flow.

The book [Nim in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/nim-in-action) says 'it's not idiomatic to use the return keyword as the last statement of the proc', but it's not explicit about `result = a + b` vs `a + b`. From the snippets around the book, the convention seems to be:

- Prefer `a + b`.
- Use `result = a + b` only if you are modifying `result`, as in `result.add(b)`.
- Use `return a` only to do an early exit from the proc.

The book also list this gotcha that won't compile:

```
proc resultVar: string = 
  result = "The result"
  "This cause an error"
```

The *reason* behind code like `result = a + b` or `return a` is that people can't get all the idiomatics, specially when they are beginners like me. I still see `for i in range(len(variable))` in Python code, which is not only non-pythonic but ugly and underperformant.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more exotic features is the implicit result variable: every procedure in Nim with a non-void return type has an implicit result variable that represents the value that will be returned [Wikipedia].

Comment: I know that part, but is there any difference to implicitly returning the last statement? Is there any reason to write 'result = xxx' or 'return xxx' when one could simply write 'xxx'